# x3dom Movietexture lagging

Tags: 3d, textures, x3d, x3dom

I managed to put videotextures on my 3d object with the following code. The problem is that it lags a lot, especially when it loops. I'm looking for a way to make it render more smoothly.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title></title>             
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://lala.cool/3d/schneosch/x3dom.js'> </script> 
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://lala.cool/3d/6328483_woesh/mesh/beertje.css'></link> 
    </head> 
    <body> 


<x3d width='500px' height='400px'> 
<scene> 
<Shape>
            <Appearance>
              <MovieTexture repeatS="false" repeatT="false" loop='true' url='"http://lala.cool/3d/eh/schneosch011_1.mp4"'/>
            </Appearance>

            <Box/>
          </Shape>
          <Transform DEF="Camera_TRANSFORM"

               >
        <Viewpoint DEF="CA_Camera"
                   centerOfRotation="0 0 0"
                   position="5.00491 -6.73519 -5.43948"
                   orientation="0.18804 0.92111 -0.34086 2.41421"
                   fieldOfView="0.8"
                   />
```

```
</scene> 
</x3d>

    </body> 
</html>
```

here you can see it in action: http://lala.cool/iwasreadingabookoflovestory.html

Answer (score 0):

It works OK on my PC. There's nothing you can do at the code level, as you can not control rendering or any parameters that might speed up the scene. Try your example in a different browser, even on a different computer. It might just this your issue.